# Can we use two different types in a single variant Button in NativeBase?

Tags: react-native, expression, native-base

Can I use two types for exp: "filled" & "rounded"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two different types in a single variant. The better way is to create a custom variant and define the required style there.